# Array in session variable (Yii)

Tags: php, session, yii

I'm trying to accomplish function that adds values to a session variable, which is array, every time user visits certain page. Here's my code from controller:

```
public function actionPut($id)
    {
        $session=new CHttpSession;
        $session->open();
        if (empty($session['the_variable'])) {
            $session['the_variable'] = array($id);
        }
        else {
            $session['the_variable'][] = $id;
        }
        $session->close();
        $this->render('test', array('session'=>$session));
    }
```

But it doesn't work. If the variable is empty, it only stores information for the first time. Next time i visit the page it doesn't add value to an array.
I've also tried `push_array` function, but no luck.
What is wrong?

Comment: You've got a $session object and trying to reference it as an array? $session->the_variable

Comment: Your constructor is missing the parenthesis.

Comment: Don't understand. Please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
public function actionPut($id)
{

     $session = Yii::app()->session;
     if (!isset($session['the_variable']) || count($session['the_variable'])==0) 
     {
         $session['the_variable'] = array($id);
     }
     else {
        $myarr = $session['the_variable'];
        $myarr[] = $id;
        $session['the_variable'] = $myarr;
     }
     $this->render('test', array('session'=>$session));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked.
But, can you explain me this lines: `$myarr = $session['the_variable'];
        $myarr[] = $id;
        $session['the_variable'] = $myarr;`

Comment: I don't have the actual concept but yii does not work with Yii::app()->session[][] = $val;

Comment: So it's the problem with Yii itself?

Comment: I can't say this is a problem with yii because session is a component which uses class CHttpSession, may be yii handles its component in such a way which does not  allow array of array assignment.

Comment: ok, but i still don't understand how the above example works. can you explain, please?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4262-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-session/

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are starting / closing a session yourself. Instead, you should let Yii handle that for you:

```
    public function actionPut($id)
    {
        $session=Yii::app()->session;
        
        if (empty($session['the_variable'])) {
            $session['the_variable'] = array($id);
        }
        else {
            $session['the_variable'][] = $id;
        }
        
        $this->render('test', array('session'=>$session));
    }
```

Also, don't close the session yourself, but let Yii handle that as well.